# Possible to insert post into dynamics CRM social pane posts using XRM SDK?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I'm using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk to interact with Dynamics CRM On-Premise. What I want to do is insert a post into Lead entity social pane posts via API.

[image]

What I did is as below:

```
var _crmUrl = _configuration.GetSection("Crm:Url").Value;
var _organizationName = _configuration.GetSection("Crm:Org").Value;
var clientCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = _configuration.GetSection("Crm:user").Value;
clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = _configuration.GetSection("Crm:pass").Value;
var crm = new OrganizationServiceProxy($"{_crmUrl}{_organizationName}", clientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential);
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet columns = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true };
var entity = await crm.RetrieveAsync("lead", new Guid(model.Id), columns, CancellationToken.None);

// INSERT POST TO entity

await crm.UpdateAsync(entity, CancellationToken.None);
```

Is it possible to insert posts using XRM SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible!
The schema name that you're looking for is [`post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/post)

To create a new `post` record should be straightforward as you already have your connection:

```
var crm = new OrganizationServiceProxy(...);
var entity = await crm.RetrieveAsync("lead", new Guid(model.Id), columns, CancellationToken.None);
```

Continuing this, you can create your new `post` record:

```
var postData = new Entity("post");
postData["text"] = "This is an automatic post from a plugin!";
postData["source"] = 1;
postData["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("lead", entity.Id);
```

The `source` column refers to whether the `post` was created automatically or manually. See [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/post#BKMK_Source).

and then save the record

```
crm.Create(postData);
```